# Handling repeating data from different individuals

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, decision-trees, data-cleaning, data-science-model

I have a dataset that has some unique values but also includes information from multiple individuals that are repeating, meaning they are describing the same attributes and can have the same or similar values.

The scenario is data from a video game to predict round success outcomes.

Example of a player:

```
Player:
    weapon: bool,
    is_alive: int,
    location: int (this is Label encoded from e.g. 'house', 'garden')
```

And in my dataset to keep a 2d array, the players are noted with upgoing numbers, so the keys look like this:

`['player_1_weapon', 'player_1_is_alive', 'player_2_weapon']` etc.

Currently, I am trying out Decision Trees, and I realize that the algorithm learns that specific player numbers are more indicative of the round outcome than others (e.g. if player_1 has a weapon its better than player_2 having a weapon), which is not desired since players can have different numbers and it should be handled more anonymously.

Additionally, on some nodes, my decision tree checks for values below a threshold for label encoded attributes like the location, which makes no sense, since the label encoded values have no relation regarding order. Maybe one-hot encoding would solve this?

Comment: You should defintely one-hot-encode categorical features. I don't understand exactly how the outcome is determined, is it based only on whether a player has a weapon and the location? Normally the player id should not be used as feature, unless the players have specific strength or something like this.

Comment: The outcome prediction should be determined by many parameters, weapon and location are only a few.

Comment: The problem with the player id's is that I am not sure how I can incorporate different players into the same data row. My only solution right now is having a `player_1_weapon` and `player_2_weapon`, or is it somehow possible to include a list of players that are all objects in machine learning? Couldn't find any real solution for that

Comment: It's a matter of designing the problem: either the player id represents an information that the model should be able to use or it doesn't. If the player id represents some characteristics which can impact the outcome, then it makes sense to use it. Anyway you would probably need features like `player_X_weapon`. But it's sometimes better to directly provide the model with a feature representing the difference, i.e. "how much better is player1's weapon?".